# MVC Windows Authentication with AD - I still have to log in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I have decorated my controller as follows

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"domain\System_Admin, domain\Survey_Admin, domain\Read_Only")]
    public class ContractController : BaseController
    {
```

I am in the process of converting a Forms Authenticated application to Windows Authentication. However I find that to access the methods in this controller, I have to login via a popup screen, defeating the purpose of using Windows Authentication.
In my web.config I have:

```
   <authentication mode="Windows" />
   <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

What more do I need to do so that the user is automatically logged in with the correct user roles?

Comment: Have you added the site to the list of trusted sites in IE?

Comment: No I haven't. Is this what needs to be done? - I don't have permissions to do that myself.

Comment: If you add the site to the list of trusted sites (Internet Options > Security > Trusted sites > Sites) you wont be prompted for the credentials. Chrome uses IE options but I think FireFox has its own settings (sorry, don't have the link to show how to set up FireFox)